# How to convert dtype categorical variable to numerical?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created `agebin` column from `age` column. I had created `agebin` by using `pd.cut()` check below:

```
traindata = data.assign(age_bins =  pd.cut(data.age, 4, retbins=False,labels=range(1, 5), include_lowest=True))

data['agebin'] = traindata['age_bins']
```

Now when I see data.info then `agebin` has dtype `category` and I want it to be numerical data because I am getting Value error while training model. How can I convert dtype:category to numerical. I am confused how dtype is categorical because when I see `data['agebin'].head()` all values are 1,2,3 or 4 but in data.info it is showing `agebin` as categorical.

I want to change `agebin` from categorical to numerical dtype.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pd.to_numeric`

```
data.agebin= pd.to_numeric(data.agebin, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thanks got it. This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

@nimrodz answers the question perfectly.

I just want to add that the reason you are getting a `category` dtype for age_bins is due to the behavior of `pd.cut`.

> out : pandas.Categorical, Series, or ndarray
>
> - An array-like object representing the respective bin for each value of
>     x. The type depends on the value of **labels**.
>
>   - sequence of scalars : returns a Series for Series x or a
>       pandas.Categorical for all other inputs. The values stored within are
>       whatever the type in the sequence is.
>   - False : returns an ndarray of integers.

If you set `labels=False` it will return an integer by default for `age_bins`, however it starts the numbering at 0. You could just add one if you want.

```
traindata = data.assign(age_bins =  pd.cut(data.age, 4, retbins=False, labels=False, include_lowest=True))
traindata['age_bins'] = traindata.age_bins+1
```

Comment: This is definitely a better way of handling the issue.